# How to smooth such a boundary？

Tags: modeling, modifiers, operator

When I use a Boolean modifier to deviate from a plane, I get this section of the object.[image: boundary] I want to make this interface smoother, but the bevel operation doesn't work and it creates a lot of extra weird planes.How can I smooth this boundary?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology won't let you bevel the edge, you can either redo a clean topology, or extrude up the top face and bevel:

[image]

Comment: Yes , it's working as expected.